# SQL: FInding a Query to Filter Products through Selected Category IDs

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql-server, inner-join

[image]

Two Tables Shown in the Image i.e. **Product** and **ProductCategory**.
Now the question is, (assume) when categories(**C_ID**) selected from front end is "**3**", "**5**", "**4**". then the output has to be "**wer**" with the help of **JOIN** to **Product** Table.

And when selected categories is "**5**", "**4**", "**8**", then the output has to be "**nothing**". Would you help me to write a SQL query to do it?
Note: Only common products has to be shown after selecting the category.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SqlServer? So you only want to output the Product when one single Product is matched?

Comment: As posted your question doesn't make much sense. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: using MS SqlServer, Yes Nicky.

Comment: assumption: every time user will have to select exact three categories ?

Comment: nope, it can be 1 or 5.

Comment: so what logic you follow in that case. if all 5 selected categories relate to only one product then you need that product name, other wise NOTHING should be the output ?

Comment: Yes, Muhammad and if selected have 2 or more products in common. then show 2 or more products, not only one.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
         declare var1 varchar(100)
      if exists (select 1 from productcategory where C_id in ('3','4','5')
         begin 
         set @var1= (select top 1 b.name 
         from productcategory a 
         join product b 
         on a.P_id=b.id) 
         end
       else set @var1='Nothing'
```

The Join operation will store the name in var1 , you can write a function that returns var1.

Comment: well try bro, read my question again. if 3, 4, 5 has common product, then show product name.

Comment: @LoneRay You never wrote that in your question. `selected from front end is "3", "5", "4". then the output has to be "wer" `. Perhaps you should read your own question again? :)

Comment: i'm sorry, bit weak in english too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT MAX(ISNULL(Name,'Nothing')) FROM
(SELECT MAX(Product.Name) AS Name
 FROM Product INNER JOIN ProductCategory ON ProductCategory.P_ID = Product.ID
 WHERE ProductCategory.C_ID IN (3,4,5)
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)Q1
```

Obviously replace `(3,4,5)` with whatever is passed in for the given setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use something like:

```
if ((select count(distinct product.name) from...) > 1) select 'Nothing'
else select distinct product.name from ...
```

or use something like this:

```
select distinct @name = product.name from ...
if (@@rowcount > 1) select 'Nothing'
else select @name
```